# How do we print all the variables during debugging in R

Tags: r

Usually, in R, when we debug, we set `options(error=recover)`, and run our functions. If it generates any errors, we enter `1` to go the top level. If we type `ls()`, it displays a list of variables at the local level of the functions. Is there is a quick way to print the current values of all these variables?

Comment: How about `mget(ls())`?

Comment: Yep, does the job!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to debugging. You are asking how to print the values of all objects in an environment. You need to "get" multiple variables and that can be done with the `mget` function: `mget(ls())`.